# Material point of origin animation

Tags: android, animation

I can't find anything on the internet regarding on how to recreate [this](http://material-design.storage.googleapis.com/videos/animation-responsive-surfaceresponse-pointorigin-do_example_large_xhdpi.webm)(Point of origin animation).

More specifically, I can't seem to find out what type of element to show when the user onClicks the ImageView and executes that point of origin animation.

I tried to use a custom DialogFragment but it doesn't work the same way like in that animation. What is Google using for that thing and where could I find some example code for it? Thanks in advance!